# Mercure hub behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: symfony, nginx, caddy, mercure

I try to deploy a Mercure hub on a server.

There is already a Symfony app (REST API) served with Apache2 (and Nginx configured in reverse proxy). My idea is to keep the API proxy to Apache2 and configure the Mercure subscriptions to be forwarded to the Mercure Hub (a Caddy server).

All is ok for the API part, but it's impossible to configure Nginx and Caddy correctly to work together. I precise that I reach the hub successfully when it's not behind Nginx. I use a custom certificate and, for some reason, each time I try to subscribe to the hub, I have this error :

> ```
> DEBUG http.stdlib http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:36250: no
> certificate available for '127.0.0.1'
> ```

If I modify my Nginx configuration with `proxy_pass https://mydomain:3000;` instead of `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000;`, the error becomes :

> ```
> DEBUG http.stdlib http: TLS handshake error from PUBLIC-IP:36250: no
> certificate available for 'PRIVATE-IP'
> ```

There is no further explaination in the Caddy or Nginx logs.

My guess is Nginx does not transfer the proper requested domain to Caddy, but I don't know why as I applied correctly the configuration instructions I found on the specification. Any help would be appreciated, thank you !

**Caddy.dev config**

```
{
    # Debug mode (disable it in production!)
    {$DEBUG:debug}

    # Port update
    http_port 3001
    https_port 3000

    # HTTP/3 support
    servers {
        protocol {
            experimental_http3
        }
    }
}

{$SERVER_NAME:localhost}

log

tls /path-to-certificate/fullchain.pem /path-to-certificate/privkey.pem

route {
    redir / /.well-known/mercure/ui/
    encode zstd gzip

    mercure {
        # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
        transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt://mercure.db}
        # Publisher JWT key
        publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
        # Subscriber JWT key
        subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
        # Permissive configuration for the development environment
        cors_origins http://localhost
        publish_origins *
        demo
        anonymous
        subscriptions
        # Extra directives
        {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
    }

    respond /healthz 200

    respond "Not Found" 404
}
```

**NGinx Virtualhost config**

```
server {
  listen      80 http2;
  server_name mercure-hub-domain.com;
  return 301 https://mercure-hub-domain.com;
}

server {
  listen      443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name mercure-hub-domain.com;

  ssl_certificate /path-to-certificate/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /path-to-certificate/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_read_timeout 24h;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_connect_timeout 300s;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  # Configuration des logs
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/my-project/access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/my-project/error.log;
}
```

**Command to launch the Mercure hub**

```
sudo SERVER_NAME='mercure-hub-domain.com:3000' DEBUG=debug MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY='MY-KEY' MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY='MY-KEY' ./mercure run -config Caddyfile.dev
```

Comment: I think you should not use https behind the reverse proxy because it is useless :
`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;`

Comment: Unfortunatly, it's not useless as the Mercure Hub must be launch in HTTPS mode to send private publications (https://mercure.rocks/spec#authorization).

Comment: @Rubix did you manage to make it works ?

Comment: @Charly : Yes, it's not perfect but it does the job. I modified a bit the nginx and caddy configurations since the post but nothing structuring.    

However, the main point is to declare a certificate in Caddy and specify it's not issued by himelf. With the following line in the Caddy configuration, I made it work :  
  
`tls /path-to-certificate/fullchain.pem /path-to-certificate/privkey.pem {
    issuer internal
}`

Comment: Hi, i'm trying the same thing with Mercure 0.15, do you use this version or still an oldest ?